# In a Rails 3 app I am trying to populate an array from the database once instead of reloading it for every page accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following pull down menu is on every page of our web site after someone logs in. For some accounts there are over 200 items in the pull down menu. I don't want to reload the array for each page.

the pull down menu:

```
<%= select_tag "current_item", options_from_collection_for_select(@all_user_items, :id, :name, @current_item) %>
```

in controller:

```
@all_user_items = Item.where("user_id = ?, current_user.id)
```

Do I have to use a global variable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: to be honest unless this is proving to be a problem, I wouldn't worry about it. The generating of the HTML will likely be much slower than the fetching of the 200 items from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data are specific to the current user you can't just cache the results in a simple variable. You need to differentiate between different users. Try something like this:

1. You can use a class `@@` or a global `$` variable with a hash indexed by the user ID.

   ```
   $user_items ||= {}
   $user_items[current_user.id] ||= Item.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
   ```

   Then instead of just using `@all_user_items` use:

   ```
   <%= select_tag "current_item", options_from_collection_for_select($user_items[current_user.id], :id, :name, @current_item) %>
   ```
2. It will be much more scalable to use Rails caching to handle it. As with the first approach you can easily run out of memory if there are too many users.

   ```
   @user_items = Rails.cache.fetch("user_items/#{current_user.id}", expires_in: 12.hours) do
     Item.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
   end
   ```

   And then in the view:

   ```
   <%= select_tag "current_item", options_from_collection_for_select(@user_items, :id, :name, @current_item) %>
   ```

Comment: Studying the cache process before implementing it. If I implement it, I'll check your response as my answer.